# Visibility property in report not working

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS report with a few graphical elements. I'd like to hide these when the report is exported out to Excel, so I've changed the `Visibility` property to:

```
=Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL"
```

Exporting the report from Report Builder to Excel works fine; the graphics are shown when viewing the report but are excluded from the `.xls` file. However, if I export the report from my ASP.Net site by executing this code:

```
    byte[] result = Myreportviewer.ServerReport.Render("Excel");
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyReport.xls");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", result.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    Response.BinaryWrite(result);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

.. the resulting file contains the graphics.

I've also tried changing `EXCEL` to `EXCELOPENXML`, with seemingly no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as we're encouraged to [answer our own questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/): it was just a good old-fashioned case-sensitivity problem. Although Report Builder doesn't appear to care whether the `RenderFormat` is `EXCEL` or `Excel`, the ASP ReportViewer component appears to only accept `Excel`. So simply changing the `Visibility` condition to

```
=Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "Excel"
```

... and everything works fine, from both Report Builder and ASP.Net.